# Nativescript Angular2 tutorial results in error

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am getting the below error with the Angular2 tutorial.  TNS Doctor is ok then why the below error?

```
'tns livesync ios --emulator --watch
Executing before-prepare hook from /Users//Documents/frontend/sample-Groceries/hooks/before-prepare/nativescript-dev-typescript.js
Found peer TypeScript 1.8.10
Project successfully prepared (ios)
Executing before-livesync hook from /Users//Documents/frontend/sample-Groceries/hooks/before-livesync/nativescript-angular-sync .js
Transferring project files...
Successfully transferred all files.
Applying changes...
Successfully synced application org.nativescript.groceries on device D28D29C3-07B6-4B60-B4B0-711475C505DE.
Executing before-watch hook from /Users//Documents/frontend/sample-Groceries/hooks/before-watch/nativescript-dev-typescript.js
Found peer TypeScript 1.8.10
Sep 17 07:34:37 Davids-iMac sampleGroceries[2934]: 1   0x105cd08d7 -[TNSRuntime executeModule:]
Sep 17 07:34:37 Davids-iMac sampleGroceries[2934]: 2   0x10587b6d2 main
Sep 17 07:34:37 Davids-iMac sampleGroceries[2934]: 3   0x109be668d start
Sep 17 07:34:37 Davids-iMac sampleGroceries[2934]: 4   0x1
Sep 17 07:34:37 Davids-iMac sampleGroceries[2934]: file:///app/tns_modules/utils/utils.js:130:72: JS ERROR TypeError: UIDevice.currentDevice is not a function. (In 'UIDevice.currentDevice()', 'UIDevice.currentDevice' is an instance of UIDevice)
Sep 17 07:34:37 Davids-iMac com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.D28D29C3-07B6-4B60-B4B0-711475C505DE.launchd_sim[2849] (UIKitApplication:org.nativescript.groceries[0xe746][2934]): Service exited due to Segmentation fault: 11
7:34:38 AM - Compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
```

I am using the new 8x Xcode.

Answer (score 5):

Dependences version of the sample-Groceries project will be updated to the latest NativeScript version soon, however you could open your package.json file and change the following versions:

`tns-ios": {"version": "2.3.0"}`

`"nativescript-angular": "1.0.0"`

`"tns-core-modules": "2.3.0"`.

You  should also be sure that `hooks`, `node_modules`, `platforms` folders has been deleted. In regard to that, With Xcode 8 some of the methods now are  properties and that will cause issues when native code has been used  in the project as it does in the sample-Groceries. As a temporary solution you could replace some code in the `status-bar-util.ts` and `grocery-list.component.ts` files.

**app/shared/status-bar-util.ts**

`UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent;` replace with `UIApplication.sharedApplication.statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent;`

**app/groceries/grocery-list/grocery-list.component.ts**

`cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor();` replace with `cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor;`